# Distinguish buttons in swt spinner

Tags: swt, spinner

I need to understand what button was pressed on the swt spinner. I tried adding listeners to swt events, but the verify, modify and selection events seem to have the same values regardless of the button pressed. The idea of getting the MouseDown coordinates and checking the vertical coordinate doesn't seems right.

Thanks, 
Nik

Comment: Why don't you just keep track of the previously selected value and every time you get an event, check if the new value is higher or lower. Based on that, you can determine which button was pressed.

Comment: Thx Baz, but i think this way is even more wrong than checking the coordinate. I think there must be a better way using some event data i can't yet find

Comment: There is none, I've checked before.

Comment: Sad to hear that, if it's true. Thx for the reply anyway